# Где мое значение после выполнения Golang Init

Tags: golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var http_endpoint string

func init() {
    http_endpoint, ok := os.LookupEnv("http_endpoint")
    fmt.Println("OK IS:", ok)
    if !ok {
        http_endpoint = "127.0.0.1:3000"
    }
    fmt.Println("INIT RESULT:", http_endpoint)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("FINAL RESULT:", http_endpoint)
}

/* OUTPUT:
OK IS: false
INIT RESULT: 127.0.0.1:3000
FINAL RESULT: 
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var http_endpoint string

func init() {
    http_endpoint = "127.0.0.1:3000"
    fmt.Println("INIT RESULT:", http_endpoint)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("FINAL RESULT:", http_endpoint)
}
/* OUTPUT
INIT RESULT: 127.0.0.1:3000
FINAL RESULT: 127.0.0.1:3000
*/
```

Where my value after init?

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64

Comment: ask the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), this is ruSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот оно, зло затенения
(англ. «*shadowing*»). Вот тут вы создали
**локальную** переменную, а не записали
в глобальную:

```golang
http_endpoint, ok := os.LookupEnv("http_endpoint")
```

Пишите вот так:

```golang
var ok book
http_endpoint, ok = os.LookupEnv("http_endpoint")
```